# parse error on input '->' when using case

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell by going through learn you a haskell for great good and one of the functions in the tutorials doesn't seem to compile. I can't figure out why, I thought it might be the indenting but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Most of the SE questions seems to be referring to the ghci and trying to set variables.

```
describeList :: [a] -> String
describeList xs = "The list is " ++ case xs of [] -> "empty."
                                               [x] -> "a singleton list."
                                               xs -> "a longer list."
```

The error I get is:

```
describeList.hs:4:95: parse error on input '->'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Works [fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/tucBMB). I would suggest you to check indentation.

Comment: Did you mix tabs and spaces?

Comment: turns out it was it was the tab settings in my vimrc that were screwing me up. I used the settings [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Vim) and now it works ok.

Comment: @Achaldo: In this case you should either a) answer your own question, b) find a duplicate to this question and vote to close it or c) delete this question.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the problem was with my tab settings on VIM. Turns out Haskell is quite particular with the indentations. I changed my vimrc file to these settings.

```
" Tab specific option
set tabstop=8                   "A tab is 8 spaces
set expandtab                   "Always uses spaces instead of tabs
set softtabstop=4               "Insert 4 spaces when tab is pressed
set shiftwidth=4                "An indent is 4 spaces
set shiftround                  "Round indent to nearest shiftwidth multiple
```

Source: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Vim